# How to call webservice from IBM portlets in RAD

Tags: web-services, wsdl, portlet

I have a wsdl file. 
I have to call the wsdl from IBM portlet in RAD. 
can someone suggest me some steps to invoke wsdl from portlet.

Comment: see this : http://www.webportalclub.com/2011/10/create-client-using-rad-to-access-web.html

Comment: the link is for creating web service..i already have wsdl file..need to call it from portlets..please suggest...

Comment: see there Generate the Client Stubs from the WSDL file

Comment: ys they r generating stub files from WSDL but how to use Portlets in this???

Comment: Anyone has any idea on this???Plz suggest